# Antiderivative of log-partition function of exponential family

Tags: exponential-family, cumulants

Let $Y$ be a random variable with distribution belonging to a minimal regular exponential family. Let $\eta $ denote the scalar-valued canonical parameter of the exponential family and let $A$ be the log-partition function of the exponential family. $A$ is strictly convex and infinitely differentiable. It is well-known that $A$ acts a a cumulant generating function for the distribution of the sufficient statistic of $Y$.

Does the antiderivative $\int A(\eta) \, d\eta$ have any interpretation? Can it be shown to coincide with the log partition function of an exponential family?

Comment: Log-partition functions depend on a parameter $\eta$. What would be this parameter if $\int \! A(\eta) d\eta$ was a log-partition function itself?

Comment: Here the integral is an indefinite type (AKA antiderivative, primitive, ...). It is also a function of $\eta$, which when differentiated with respect to $\eta$, gives $A(\eta)$.